# If statement that changes value of another cell than where the function is contained

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a range of cells that either have a "Y" or "N" in them. I als0[image] have a "Score" cell that starts with a value of 4. I want to search those cells and if they contain a single "N" then I want the value in cell $S$17 (Score Cell) to be subtracted by 1. If they are all "Y" then I want the number value in $S$17 to remain the same. The formula itself is in cell $S$17 so when I have this formula =IF(COUNTIF(S2:S6,"N"),SUM(S17,-1),S17) it is giving me a circular Reference error. Is there a way to post this formula in a different cell but have the output posted in cell $S$17? I was thinking something like =IF(COUNTIF(S2:S6,"N"),S17 = SUM(S17,-1),S17). I know this isn't correct syntax but thats the idea. Or if thats not possible just avoid the circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple answer here if I understand your Q:

If you want to subtract 1 for EACH "N":

```
= 4 - COUNTIF(S2:S6, "N")
```

If you want to ONLY subtract 1 for ANY quantity of "N":

```
= IF(COUNTIF(S2:S6, "N")>0, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Well there is going to be multiple formulas that will either add one or subtract one from the current score value. So I cant just assign 3 or 4 to it i need to add or subtract one from the current value which could be anywhere between 1-4 depending on the situation.

Comment: @BrianWolf Then how do you get 4 currently?